# CST_PASSWORD is missing from avectra netFORUM xml response

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, wsdl, avectra

I have successfully logged into avectra netforum through valid credentials, im able to get Auth token/ CST key from other service responses.

I'm passing auth token & memeber's WEBIndividualGet to Gets an individual's Info.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <AuthorizationToken xmlns="http://www.avectra.com/2005/">
      <Token>bbb887e3-7716-4af8-97cf-68c2d977e28a</Token>
    </AuthorizationToken>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <WEBIndividualGet xmlns="http://www.avectra.com/2005/">
      <key>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</key>
    </WEBIndividualGet>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

In response, in "customer" XML , i didn't receive  value ..ie., cst_web_password variable is not there/set.

While checking the same scenario before a month, im getting this field in response. Please let me know, what may be the reason, im not getting this field.

Thanks,
Stupid

Answer (score 1):

The web method WEBIndividualGet doesn't return a password. Passwords in netFORUM are hashed anyway, so getting that value wouldn't be useful to you.